# When does setVisibility() not fire onVisibilityChanged() in a view?

Tags: android

I have a problem where in a specific situation when I call `setVisibility(GONE)` inside my custom view, its `onVisibilityChanged` method doesn't get called and it actually doesn't hide the view although `getVisibility()` returns `8` (or `GONE`) afterwards.

Here is how I know the visibility changes but onVisibilityChanged is not called.

```
@Override
protected void onVisibilityChanged(@NonNull View changedView, int visibility) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onVisibilityChanged: " + visibility);
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
}

@Override
public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
    super.setVisibility(visibility);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "setVisibility: " + visibility);
}

public void hide(){
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "before hide visibility: " + getVisibility());
    setVisibility(GONE);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "after hide visibility: " + getVisibility());
}
```

Normally when I call `hide()` I see these lines in the log:

> before hide visibility: 0
>
> onVisibilityChanged: 8
>
> setVisibility: 8
>
> after hide visibility: 8

But in a spicific situation when I call `hide()` I get these lines in the log and the view isn't hidden afterwards although `getVisibility()` returns `8`:

> before hide visibility: 0
>
> setVisibility: 8
>
> after hide visibility: 8

So when in general does this happen? When does `setVisibility` not call `onVisibilityChanged`?

Don't ask what my specific situation is. But please provide every general situation where this might happen.

Comment: "Don't ask what my specific situation is" seems like a refusal to provide a MCVE

Comment: @BenP. My question is provide every general situation where this thing happens and not solve this specific problem I have. If you give every situation I will see if it includes mine. First off there is too much code to go through if I want to explain my situation, and secondly I know as soon as I mention it has to do with rotation all the wrong (and generic) answers will flow in.

Comment: Well, if you put specific steps to reproduce it in your question I would think about answering it, but right now this is way too broad to bother with imo.

Comment: @BenP. Apart from RobCo's answer do you even know a situation where this might happen? because if you're not gonna bother with providing that, I don't think you are going to bother reproducing this problem either because it is too much code to go through and I'm not going to put the code up here)

Answer (score 4):

### It is called only when the view is attached in the hierarchy.

The call to setVisibility looks like this:

```
public void setVisibility(@Visibility int visibility) {
    setFlags(visibility, VISIBILITY_MASK);
}
```

The `setFlags` method is a long one where a bunch of different view properties are changed and handled, but the noticable part is this:

```
 if ((changed & VISIBILITY_MASK) != 0) {
      // if visiblity changed...
      ...
      if (mAttachInfo != null) { // true if attached in view hierarchy
            dispatchVisibilityChanged(this, newVisibility); // onVisibilityChanged is called from here 
            ...
```

---

So you will see your described behaviour on a view that's not attached to a fragment or activity.

Comment: But I can see the view in the activity and onAttachedToWindow is called before I call hide() on it. Is there any other situation where this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

you can use another way to solve this problem

create a method like this

```
private void stateCheck(View view){

    if (view.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
    // handle gone state
    }else if (view.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
    // handle invisible state
    }else{
    // handle other states
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [View.onVisibilityChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)

> Called when the visibility of the view or an ancestor of the view has
>   changed.

As this says, `onVisibilityChanged` will only be called when visibility is changed.

```
public void hide(){
    setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

This will be called in two cases.

1. When visibility is `VISIBLE`.
2. When visibility is `INVISIBLE`.

**This will not be called if View visibility is already set to GONE.**

#### Solution

So how can you capture all the events of visibility?

Override `setVisibility` method in your custom view class. This method will be called every time visibility is called. Like below

```
public class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        super.setVisibility(visibility);
        System.out.println("CustomTextView.setVisibility " + visibility);
    }
}
```

#### Update

I could not get this situation. But here is a workaround for getting rid of your problem.

If you are sure, that your code either calls `onVisibilityChanged` or `setVisibility` when visibility is changed. Then you can do this.

```
customTextView.setOnVisibilityChange(new CustomTextView.OnVisibilityChange() {
    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

    }
});
```

Here is the sample view class.

```
public class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    private int currentVisibility = 0;
    OnVisibilityChange onVisibilityChange;


    public void setOnVisibilityChange(OnVisibilityChange onVisibilityChange) {
        this.onVisibilityChange = onVisibilityChange;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
        callback(visibility);
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        super.setVisibility(visibility);
        callback(visibility);
    }

    private void callback(int visibility) {
        if (currentVisibility != visibility && onVisibilityChange != null)
            onVisibilityChange.onVisibilityChange(visibility);
        currentVisibility = visibility;
    }

    public interface OnVisibilityChange {
        void onVisibilityChange(int visibility);
    }
}
```

Comment: But as you can see in the log, the visibility was different before I set it to GONE and after that the visibility was changed to GONE but still onVisibilityChanged is not called and the view does not hide. I have overridden setVisibility (see it in my question). The problem is setVisibility doesn't call onVisibilityChanged even though the view is anchored and visibility is different than before. So there is probably another situation where this happens which is not very obvious.

Comment: I tried myself with sample, I am getting perfect result. Can you try with individual code? Let me know if you can achieve this in seperate code, if true, then there can be some issue in your existing code.

Comment: Of course in normal situations this code works. You don't even need to override setVisibility for that. I'm asking to give me all the situations where this doesn't work. So far your answer and RobCo's tell me 2 situations. But there has to be more because none of them apply to mine.

Comment: How can I reproduce this condition?

Comment: It is complicated and there is too much code involved... that is why I didn't specify exact situation and asked for every situation. I thought there was an obvious if condition or something in the android code where you can find all of these situations but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: There is not any more conditions. Perhaps your code has some issue. Above is all information about `onVisibilityChanged`.

Comment: How do you know there is not any other conditions? Can you show me the android code where these conditions are specified?

Comment: I know because Android has nothing to hide, if there were some condition, they would have mentioned https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View

Comment: They make perfect documentation, because many developers work on it.

Comment: No they don't. You know how many terrible situations I found myself in where I had to search for hours only to find some discussion in google code website from like 4 years ago where someone said it was a bug (and no one has fixed it yet)!

Comment: Bug and documentation are different things. If they make conditions they document it. The  only way to ask help is that tell the way to reproduce this condition. Or you have to find issue in your code. Or you can post all your code in git and give link.

Comment: Well this might be bug, who knows. Bug is a condition where developers haven't considered.

Comment: @ROAR We are not android code creator, we also use resources to find some solution. so only way that you can expect solution is to let us know the reproducing way.

Comment: If what you are saying is true and this is a bug (an unexpected condition), then fine it's a bug. I never asked anyone to fix my situation, I just wanted to know every known condition. I'll deal with the bug my way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181080/discussion-between-khemraj-and-roar).